# How to obtain google + id from app engine user?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, firebase

I'm migrating my data to google app engine from firebase.
When I log in to the site using google auth I can retrieve the users google + id from firebase.

but when I am exporting the user data from app engine, the user_id() function does not give me the same value.

I believe I've either got to find a way for firebase to get the email from the google oauth provider, or figure out a way to get google+ ID from a user's email when I'm exporting from app engine.

TL;DR
How do i get the google+ ID from someone's gmail address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is not possible.